# Getting indices for the first non-NA values

Tags: r, dataframe, na

I have a large data set of econ. data, all of which have different start dates. I'm trying to find the index of each individual start date (ie first non-zero)

I have tried for loops and which(!is.na) and Position function. With the for loops, I get an error of "closure' not subsettable.

```
x <- c(NA, NA, NA, 6, 5, 3, 7, 2, 7, 8)
y <- c(NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 3, 5, 6, 3, 9)
z <- c(1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10)
mydata <- data.frame(x, y, z)

for (j in 1:ncol(mydata)){
index[j] <- min(which(!is.na(mydata[,j])))}

Position(function(x) !is.na(x), mydata)
```

I expect the outcome to be index = c(4, 6, 1).

I get an error of not subsettable for the for loop, and an error of only first element being used for the Position function

also, I don't have access to dplyr.

Comment: Try  `head(which(!is.na(mydata), arr.ind = TRUE)[, 1], 3)#
[1] 4 5 6`

Comment: `Position` will work, it just doesn't work on a `data.frame` all at once, you have to loop it over each column - `sapply(mydata, Position, f=Negate(is.na))` for instance.

Comment: If it is column index `mydata %>% summarise_all(~which.max(!is.na(.)))`

Answer (score 3):

`Position` will work, it just doesn't work on a `data.frame` all at once, you have to loop it over each column. E.g.:

```
sapply(mydata, Position, f=Negate(is.na)) 
#x y z 
#4 6 1
```

Answer (score 2):

We can use `summarise_all`

```
library(dplyr)
mydata %>% 
   summarise_all(~which.max(!is.na(.)))
```

---

Or with `which`

```
indx <- which(!is.na(mydata), arr.ind = TRUE)
tapply(indx[,1], indx[,2], FUN = first)
# 1 2 3 
# 4 6 1
```

Answer (score 1):

We can do this:

```
sapply(mydata, function(xx) min(which(!is.na(xx))))

#> x y z 
#> 4 6 1
```